# How to use "jquery-param" npm package in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript-typings

The [jquery-param](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-param) npm package has the functionality I need in my Angular9 project. I noticed it doesn't have typings for typescript so I also added [@types/jquery-param](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery-param) as dependency. I've tried importing in different ways to no avail. I've also read various answers about [DefinitelyTyped](https://definitelytyped.org/) and typings but can't manage to find the solution. Made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ep2i7s) with intended usage if someone is willing to take a look.

**Update:**
**TL;DR:** I managed to import and use it. Now the project compiles and works great<s>, but the VSCode's checker marks an error in the import statement</s>. After closing and reopening VSCode it no longer shows error in the import. It seems it only load changes to *tsconfig.json* on app start.

In [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ep2i7s) works great with just the typings and importing with `import param from 'jquery-param';`.

Went ahead and installed both packages in my real project. Then had trouble importing as the compiler complained:

> ERROR in src/app/shared/services/http.service.ts:4:24 - error TS2497: This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag and referencing its default export.

This is because of how the typings are exported, as [@wtho mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62686766/8714275) and as stated by:

> index.d.ts(8, 1): This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.

Tried importing with `import * as params from 'jquery-params'` and other ways using curly braces, didn't work.

So I added

```
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

to *tsconfig.json* as some answers mentioned.

Now the project compiles and works great.

**Note about *jquery-param***:
This package exports a sigle function equivalent to *jQuery.param()*. This allows to encode a nested object to pass it as a query string in a GET request. I will be using it in requests to an API like this:

```js
const params = {
  pageIndex: 1,
  pageSize: 10,
  filter: [
    { key: 'active', value: true }
  ],
  sort: [
    { key: 'username', value: 'ascend' }
  ]
}

url += '?' + param(params);

this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe(
  ...
);
```

I went for this package because couldn't do it using Angular API, and most answers said spin your own function to encode nested objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before ES modules were introduced, packages often exported a single function as default export. You can import these using the ES modules syntax `import param from 'jquery-param'` and just setting `"esModuleInterop": true` in your base `tsconfig.json`.

If VSCode still complains, make sure you do not have some outdated TypeScript extensions active.

Here is a working [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-arrpar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

It also worked for me locally with Angular `v10.0.2` and TypeScript `v3.9.5`.

---

Note that url query parameters are not designed to transport complex object. If possible, switching to a HTTP POST request might be the better solution.

Comment: I've made an update about the import and why _jquery-param_.